# Regex to delete text before Email Address

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

**This is what I have:**

```
FirstName1 LastName2 name1@email.com ID1
FirstName2 LastName2 name2@email.com ID2
... and so on.
```

**This is what I need:**

```
name1@email.com ID1
name2@email.com ID2
... and so on.
```

As mentioned in the title, I'd like to know how to achieve the above results using regex.

Comment: [Regular Expressions Tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and [RegExr is an online tool to learn, build, & test Regular Expressions](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*\h(\S+@.+)$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
    .*      # 0 or more any character but newline
    \h      # 1 horizontal space
    (       # start group 1
        \S+     # 1 or more non space character
        @       # @
        .+      # 1 or more any character but newline
    )       # end group
$       # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]